# Fear of mac Spoofing. Two Mac addresses appearing on Router page with only 1 digit variation

Tags: wifi, attacks, wireless, spoofing, mac-spoofing

I have tried looking into Info Sec's posts for a related issue but couldn't find a solution as my problem is a bit specific.

I have been having connectivity issues, and as paranoid as I can get, i wanted to see if there was any foul play as I was finding a lot of strange, sporadic appearances of Wifi networks in my vicinity.

Prior to these networks appearing I had no connectivity issues. Regardless, to simplify and get to the point, I went to take a look at the attached devices on my router administration page to suss out any potential intruders.

I've just come up to see two mac address appearing on the list, however I am the only connected device. To clarify I am connecting to a Wireless Extender.

This is where the issue is: The two Mac Addresses are ALMOST ALIKE save for a 1 digit variation. However what is interesting is that the Mac address that is not my NIC's original physical address is assigned to my IP and Vendor {MSI} while my original Mac address is listed as an unknown.

(I have attached the image of my devices page below to show this.)

Is there a possibility that I may be Mac Spoofed or am i being too worried? I am not familiar with protocols or measures used by routers as I am a home user. Perhaps the router needs to duplicate my mac address and amend it for internet connectivity?

[image: Attached image of Router Admin Page]

Comment: Do you have any other devices connected that may just have that mac adress? Or perhaps a virtual machine on your PC?

Comment: Some NICs have 2 MACs for 2GHz and 5GHz bands

Comment: Some devices can emulate MAC addresses to avoid tracking: http://www.imore.com/closer-look-ios-8s-mac-randomization

Comment: @BlackMagic  I think it could be the two bands from my NIC for 5GHZ and 2GHZ that are appearing in the mac tables (after indication from @schroeder) as I've tried connecting to both bands within the same hour (based on the idea that mac tables only update every hour [?]

Comment: @BlackMagic Ill monitor from now on on one band and see if the duplicate appears. I dont have an VM software or a Virtual Machine running on my PC. Thanks for your response

Comment: Hooray, you have a client that at least TRIES to apply MAC address randomization!

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your connectivity problems are because the new wifi networks are conflicting on the same channels. Change channels.

The reason why you are not coming up with answers on infosec forums is because this isn't an infosec issue, this is a basic networking issue. Many devices have the 2 MACs for a single device. There is actually a duplicate of t

By the way, the router does not modify your MAC for connectivity.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I think that makes the best sense as I have been trying to connect to both bands to suss out the connectivity issue and thus that explains the two Mac addresses. 

 Apologies for posting out of context as i wasn't sure if this was a networking issue or intrusion due to my lack of knowledge.

 Just to ask, from what i understand 5ghz is void of interference so i'm wondering why my 5GHZ band experiences the same connection issues. My extender receives both bands from the main router. Interference on the modem's end is likely?